# Visual Studio Build Error -> Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets: DLL could not be found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 where I am using NET Core, I have three class libraries. Here are my class libraries:

[image]

- ClassLibrary1 references -> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
- ClassLibrary1 uses *.NETCoreApp 1.0* while Caching Redis uses *.NET Standard 1.5*

My Problem is when I am building my solution, it seems ClassLibrary1 couldn't find the dll of Redis since the dlls are placed in artifact folder in the solution's directory.

If I check the Build Output, it says that:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5)


 error : C:\Caching-1.0.0\src\ClassLibrary1\error CS0006:
 Metadata file 'C:\Caching1.0.0\src\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis\bin\Debug\netstandard1.5\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.dll'
 could not be found
```

Line 262: of Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets

[image]

It seems the dlls are built and placed in the artifacts folder directory in the project solution. The File System Struture of the project is:

[image]

There is no any bin folder in the Cahing projects, how i can change that to make the bins generated in their corresponding projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the *xproj* file for Caching projects, it contains the build information, where it redirects the output to the artifact folder:

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>


<OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\bin\</OutputPath>
```

I changed both of them to point to its project folder directory

1. BaseIntermediateOutputPath -> `.\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)`
2. OutputPath -> `.\bin\`

Then, the classLibrary1 can find the required referenced dlls now.

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, h.salman. If so, please mark it as the answer, so it would help other member who meet the same issue as yours:)